# Trouble installing MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 10

Tags: miktex, installing, windows

I have PC with fresh install of Windows 10. I am now trying to install the version of MiKTeX 2.9, but am running into same installation problem.  The install starts fine (Net install, basic install, full install, 32-bit, 64-bit, or ProTeXt), but stops at the same error each time - see below.  Anyone have ideas how to fix this?  Much appreciated.

> An error occurred:
>     source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp
>     source line: 418
>     message: Permission denied: path="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64/biber.exe"
>     info: path="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64/biber.exe"

Comment: Please try to install in `admin` rights

Answer (score 6):

For some reason the file locations like:

```
C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\.....
```

was getting set to "read only" automatically during installation (in my system).

I did the following and it worked.

1. Temporarily disable the Antivirus (McAfee)
2. Manually open the folder `C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\...` Then right click, go to properties and unset the Attribute Read Only. When windows asks, tell it to do it recursively for all the subfolders.

After that the installation runs smoothly and I was able to compile the TeX files (I was using Winedt as the editor).

I am not sure if disabling the antivirus was essential though.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) and thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

When the installer starts, choose install for All users. It will change the path to C:\Programs\MiKTex. This will solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure about the path? Won't it be something like: `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9`. Are there any extra requirements (like administrator rights) required. Please consider these things in your answer.

Comment: Program files and Programs are similar in Windows 10. Miktex version changes that's why I mentionned MiKTeX only. If a dude see this comment in 2500 it won't be the 2.9 just saying. No Administrator righrs are required.